# Determining if modular relation is a function

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic

I'm asked to determine if the following relation from $\mathbb Z_6$ to $\mathbb Z_9$ is a function:

$$f(x)=\{([x]_6,[x]_9)\in\mathbb Z_6 \times \mathbb Z_9: x\in \mathbb Z\}$$

I know that if this is true, I must prove that $\forall\;x\in\mathbb Z,\not\exists\;a\;|\;f(a)=b_1\land b_2$. Naturally to disprove, I must show the existence of an $x$ with two output values.

However, I'm a bit confused by the modular equivalence classes. For example, if I consider $[1]_6$, I know that both $7$ and $19$ are elements of said class. However, $7\mapsto[7]_9$ while $19\mapsto[1]_9$. Is this a counterexample or have I messed up?

Comment: If I get this well, your map is the following: $f: \mathbb{Z}_6 \to \mathbb{Z}_9: [x]_6 \mapsto [x]_9$. Then you have indeed that $[7]_6 = [19]_6$ although $[7]_9 \neq [19]_9$, so this is not a function. (This is worded by saying that 'the function is not well-defined' since the image depends on the chosen representative of the source).

Comment: @Student Would this be a valid argument then?

Consider $x=7$ and $x=19$. 

We know that $7,\;19\in[1]_6$.

We quickly see that $7\mapsto [7]_9$

We also see that $19\mapsto[1]_9$. 

Since $\exists\;a\;|\;f(a)=b_1\land b_2$, we know this is not a function.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice counterexample :) anyway, try to avoid using quantors (such as $\exists$) in proves. Full sentences are easier to read (I mean that I would write the part $\exists a \mid f(a) = ...$ in a senctence) but the idea is correct :)